# How to center and zoom on a clicked point in canvas

Tags: javascript, html, canvas

I am building an interactive map of a small geographical area using HTML canvas. The canvas will be the full width and height of the map image used. The map will have a few points dotted on it, and when one is clicked, the canvas should centre on this point and then zoom in on it.

I have so far tried this by using `translate` on the drawing context, drawing the map image so that the clicked point sits in the centre of the canvas, and then using `scale` to zoom, as follows:

```
var clickX = e.offsetX || (e.pageX - canvas.offsetLeft);
var clickY = e.offsetY || (e.pageY - canvas.offsetTop);

clickedPoint = { x: clickX, y: clickY };

ctx.translate(
    canvas.width/2 - clickedPoint.x,
    canvas.height/2 - clickedPoint.y
);
ctx.scale(2, 2);
```

However, when I draw at this point, the image doesn't appear where expected. I'm guessing because the translated point doesn't line up after the scale function, as the translate happens correctly without the scale, but I can't seem to get this working - can anyone explain how to resolve this?

EDIT: example link - http://staging.clicky.co.uk/canvas/

Answer (score 4, accepted):

To scale and zoom at a point on the canvas you must know the current zoom / scale and current origin. If you do not track this information you can not correctly scale at a point on the canvas.

If you have the scale and origin which from default is `scale = 1`, and `origin = {x:0,y:0}`

```
// scale  is current scale
// origin is current origin
function scaleAt (at, amount) { // at in screen coords amount is amount to scale
    scale *= amount;
    origin.x = at.x - (at.x - origin.x) * amount;
    origin.y = at.y - (at.y - origin.y) * amount;
};

var scale = 1;
const origin = {x : 0, y : 0};


// in mouse event
// scale is change in scale
scaleAt(clickedPoint,2); // scale 2 times at clickedPoint
// then set the transform
ctx.setTransform(scale,0,0,scale,origin.x,origin.y)
```

To center a point on an image at the center of the canvas using a fixed scale

```
// scale and origin from above code.
// newScale is absolute scale
function scaleMoveCenter (point, newScale) { 
    scale = newScale;
    origin.x = canvas.width / 2 - point.x * scale;
    origin.y = canvas.height / 2 - point.y * scale;
}
// in mouse event
scaleMoveCenter (clickedPoint,2);
// then set the transform
ctx.setTransform(scale,0,0,scale,origin.x,origin.y)
```

If the canvas already has a scale and origin set that is not default you need to find the point in that coordinate system.

```
// 
const realPos = {};
realPos.x = (clickedPoint.x - origin.x ) / scale;
realPos.y = (clickedPoint.y - origin.y ) / scale;

// increase scale by 2
scaleMoveCenter (realPos ,scale * 2);
// then set the transform
ctx.setTransform(scale,0,0,scale,origin.x,origin.y)
```

Comment: Thanks, I've managed to get this to work - however I'm now working on animating this to zoom and pan over to the clicked point. I'm trying to get the steps between the default origin (presumably 0, 0) and the new origin, and update this along with the new scale at each frame of the animation, but I'm not even close at the minute.. any advice you can give would be very helpful!

Comment: @jtrich You can interpolate scale and origin, though as scale is a multiplier the best results will need a non linear (polynomial) interpolation for the origin or scale. But try the linear interpolation, if the scale difference is small then you may be happy with the look.

Comment: Apologies, didn't explain too well - I've got the zoomed point working as you described, but not actually sure where to start/end the interpolation! I thought I could go from 0, 0 to the clicked point and account for the scale at each point but it's way off. I'm still pretty new to this so if you could give me the basics here that'd be great, thanks

Comment: @jtrich Sorry but I am not sure what you are asking, the origin can be anywhere and will depend on how you are rendering the image. Generally you would have the origin where you want the image center to be (at start and end of move) and you render the image offset by half its size `ctx.drawImage(img,- img.width / 2 , -img.height / 2);`

Comment: That makes sense, I've adjusted this now so my origin is currently at the center of the image. Then when i want to zoom on a point, do i interpolate from this point to the new position **at the current scale** and then adjust it based on the new scale at each frame? Or do i need the points' coordinates at the final (zoomed) scale? Hope that makes sense...